# Linq is weird or I'm stupid?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Why does this work:

```
result = (from e in db.CampaignCodes where e.Code.Equals("") && 
e.Domain.Equals(null) select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

But not (result is null):

```
String code = "";
String domain = null;

result = (from e in db.CampaignCodes where e.Code.Equals(code) &&
 e.Domain.Equals(domain) select e).FirstOrDefault();
```

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does indeed sound quite odd. LINQ to SQL may well notice the difference between getting the value from a variable and getting it from a constant, but I wouldn't have expected it to make any difference.

I strongly recommend that whenever LINQ to SQL appears to be behaving oddly, you turn the context logging on and see what query it's actually executing in each case.

EDIT: The other answers around the overloading aspect are really interesting. What happens if you declare the `domain` variable as type `object` instead of `string` in the second query, or cast the `null` to `string` in the first query?

Comment: Not having gotten around to using LinqToSql yet, my answer is supposition - which probably means I'm overly complicating things! Yours is definitely the more "practically useful" answer =)

Comment: Certainly turning the log on should take at least *some* of the mystery away :)

Comment: I don't remember exactly what was the problem, but we did have some issues with comparing for null values. SQL compared things that were null a bit differently than is done in C#.

Comment: Yes, SQL null values aren't equal to anything else.

Comment: @Svish @Rob @Niels @Jon: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Iain's answer:

Depending on what overloads of e.Domain.Equals() there are, passing a null string variable may hit a different one than passing null? I'm not sure what the rules would be here, but I suspect the compiler might prefer an e.Domain.Equals(object variable) to e.Domain.Equals(string variable) when explicitly given "just" null, rather than a string variable that has been set as null?

Answer (score 4):

a null string - domain - isn't the same as just passing null?

Answer (score 1):

Figuread it out through logging, these are my results:

I get the following results:

Works:

```
(from e in CampaignCodes where e.Code.Equals(code) && e.Domain.Equals(null) select e).FirstOrDefault().Dump();

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Domain], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[CampaignId], [t0].[PathId], [t0].[DescriptionText], [t0].[DeleteFlag], [t0].[Created]
FROM [CampaignCodes] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Code] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Domain] IS NULL)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.8
```

Doesn't Work:

```
(from e in CampaignCodes where e.Code.Equals(code) && e.Domain.Equals(domain) select e).FirstOrDefault().Dump();

SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Domain], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[CampaignId], [t0].[PathId], [t0].[DescriptionText], [t0].[DeleteFlag], [t0].[Created]
FROM [CampaignCodes] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Code] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Domain] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) []
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.
```

8

so

By rewriting  my linq2sql to:

```
(from e in CampaignCodes where e.Code.Equals(code) && ((domain==null && e.Domain.Equals(null))||e.Domain.Equals(domain)) select e).FirstOrDefault().Dump();
```

I get:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Domain], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[CampaignId], [t0].[PathId], [t0].[DescriptionText], [t0].[DeleteFlag], [t0].[Created]
FROM [CampaignCodes] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Code] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Domain] = @p1)
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [test]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 14; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [mydomain.se]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.8
```

When domain isn't null and:

```
SELECT TOP (1) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Domain], [t0].[ClientId], [t0].[CampaignId], [t0].[PathId], [t0].[DescriptionText], [t0].[DeleteFlag], [t0].[Created]
FROM [CampaignCodes] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Code] = @p0) AND (([t0].[Domain] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[Domain] = @p1))
-- @p0: Input NVarChar (Size = 4; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [test]
-- @p1: Input NVarChar (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2005) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.21022.8
```

When it is.

But I'd hoped that there would be a nices methods for this...