# Entity Framework - MySQL - Null Comparison!

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, null

Whats wrong with following code? :(

```
int? parentFolderId = null;
if( this.Request.QueryString ["folderId"] != null )
    parentFolderId = Convert.ToInt32( this.Request.QueryString ["folderId"] );
f = ( from x in this.EntityDataContext.folders
        where x.parent_id == parentFolderId
        select x ).ToList();
```

It returns nothing! Though there ARE records in database with parent_id as NULL.

However, when I explicitly state NULL; it works!

```
f = ( from x in this.EntityDataContext.folders
        where x.parent_id == null
        select x ).ToList();
```

What could be the issue?

PS: I hate working with mysql using Entity Framework .... every damn simple thing has million issues!

Comment: not even this is working: where x.parent_id == ( parentFolderId == null ? null : parentFolderId )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is connector bug and I have reported at mysql.

Comment: It was an EF bug and it's going to be fixed in .net 4.5 http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title#suggestion-1015361

Answer (score 3):

Long Shot

```
f = ( from x in this.EntityDataContext.folders
                where ((parentFolderId!=null && x.parent_id == parentFolderId)
                        ||(parentFolderId==null && x.parent_id == null))
                select x ).ToList();
```

Yeah, this seams wired, and I guess your first example should work just fine with MsSql.
Maybe it's time to file a bug to authors of Linq to MySql ?

Comment: @effkay @Alexander: This is a problem with [Entity Framework itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework).

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of problem in sql server and in sql server the generated query looks like "parent_id = null" when you are working on a nullable field. And that query returns nothing even parent_id is null.

The tricky way in here is, you should force EF to create a query like "parent_id is null" and the code I tried in linq was;

```
if(parentFolderId.HasValue)
{
    f = ( from x in this.EntityDataContext.folders
                where x.parent_id == parentFolderId
                select x ).ToList();
}
else
{
    f = ( from x in this.EntityDataContext.folders
                where !x.parent_id.HasValue
                select x ).ToList();
}
```

I know this does not seem a perfect way to do this but, this is how I could get rid of that issue.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution - EF seems to be doing its own "magic" in the background with LINQ. We had huge problems with EF on one of our projects and have since ditched it for nHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find there's an issue involving using DBNull or something similar. I would think that in the second case (where you explicitly state "null") that Linq is automatically transforming it to DBNull in the background.

perhaps try something along the lines of:

```
where x.parent_id == ( parentFolderId == null ? DBNull.Value : parentFolderId )
```

Hope that puts you on the right track!

Comment: already tried this: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Neither this is working :( . where x.active == 1 && x.parent_id == ( parentFolderId == null ? null : parentFolderId ). I HATE to add an if/else statement :(