# Databinding and Nullable does not seem to work together

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding

Can someone explain why data binding against a nullable property in an ADO Data Entity Model does not seem to work.  I have a decimal field named "Weight" that when it is set to allow nulls in the database, I can not seem to change the value on a windows form.  However if I turn off the allow nulls in the database and update the model, the databinding works as i expect.  Looking at the Designer.cs file the only difference I can tell is the underlying value seems to be a decimal versus a decimal?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be related to [this nasty bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework) *(there was a microsoft connect bug report, but the EF team apparently deleted all the bug reports...)*