# Linq Query with Contains and Nullable Value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a method for searching which looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Result> Search(string searchText)
{

     return _context.Person.Where(x => x.Contains(searchText));
}
```

I want to be able to call this function with `searchText` being null/empty and get all of the records back.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
return _context.Person.Where(x => x.Contains(searchText ?? ""));
```

is there another way to accomplish this besides breaking it up into two steps and checking `searchString` in an if statement before applying it to the query?

Comment: related (but not your specific problem here): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework

Comment: Is `Contains` a method of your `Person` class? Which searches for FirstName and LastName and so on? How did you even get the original version `_context.Person.Where(x => x.Contains(searchText))` working with LINQ to Entities? Can you show this method?

Comment: @Sla http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/18/how-to-do-in-and-like-clause-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

Comment: I see, but the examples there are quite other types of queries than your case. In the link are queries like `Where(x => x.City.Contains(searchText))` which is the `Contains` method of a `string` (the EF provider can map that to SQL statements) and not a user defined method `Contains` on your `Person` class like you seem to have. (`x` in your code above is a `Person` and not a `string`.)

Comment: oh im sorry, i changed my code around for a quick example..mine is more like _context.Person.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(searchText))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<Result> Search(string searchText)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        return _context.Person;
    else
        return _context.Person.Where(x => x.Contains(searchText));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
_context.Person.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) ? true : x.Contains(searchText));
```

Comment: Nice and shortest way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I try all solutions and just below solution worked for me

```
query = query.Where(e =>  e.CategoryType.HasValue && categoryTypes.Contains(e.CategoryType.Value));
```

[Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4114)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
return _context.Person.Where(x => 
   string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || 
   x.Contains(searchText)
);
```

This is a pattern I use a lot when I have parameters I want to apply only if they are set.

Answer (score 0):

```
return _context.Person.Where(x =>string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) ? true : x.Contains(searchText));
```

or

```
public IEnumerable<Result> Search(string searchText)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) ? _context.Person : _context.Person.Where(x => x.Contains(searchText));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And a less efficient way... Not sure if this is semantically correct but you get the idea...

```
return _context.Person.Where((x, index) => x.Contains(searchText ?? x[index]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Person` is a class `Contains` seems to be method of this class. An expression like `Where(x => x.Contains(searchText))` or `Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || x.Contains(searchText))` where x is a Person won't work at all with LINQ to Entities, even with a simple class like ...

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Contains(string searchText)
    {
        return Name.Contains(searchText);
    }
}
```

... it will throw an exception because LINQ to Entities can't translate this method to a storage expression. `Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText) || x.Name.Contains(searchText))` would work though.