# Nullable int not working as expected in LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The following works as expected (LINQ to Entities):

```
var topics = (from t in ctx.Topics where t.SubjectId == subjectId && t.ParentId == null select new { t.Title, t.Id }).ToList();
```

However, the following returns nothing:

```
int? parent = null;
var topics = (from t in ctx.Topics where t.SubjectId == subjectId && t.ParentId == parent select new { t.Title, t.Id }).ToList();
```

Topic.ParentId is a nullable int. It's easy to work around, but this puzzles me. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework/4262617#4262617

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are definately not the first person to observe this... interesting... behavior.

http://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/607404/entity-framework-and-linq-to-sql-incorrectly-handling-nullable-variables

In short, it's difficult to handle different ways of expressing null.

Comment: Thank you. From the link in your answer, I found an easy workaround: t.ParentId.Equals(parent). But how strange! I'm glad it's not just me going crazy!

Comment: @James, I though this work around only works for Linq to SQL and not Linq to Entities... Did it work for Linq to Entities for you?

Comment: @zespri No, I posted too soon! It works when parent is null, but not in other cases. I ended up with if (parent==null) ...