# How to select null values with LINQ to SQL and DbLinq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, sqlite, dblinq

When I

```
bool? isApproved = null;
db.Table.Where(item => item.IsApproved == isApproved).Count();
```

the last line value is 0. But when I

```
db.Table.Where(item => item.IsApproved == null).Count();
```

the value is correct.

I'm using [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), [DbLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) and [DbMetal](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/wiki/DbMetal).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i query for null values in entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework) (Note that the solution deals with both L2SQL and L2EF)

Comment: So your _not_ using Linq2Sql... ?

Comment: @Magnus Are Linq2Sql and DbLinq mutually exclusive? I thought that you had to use Linq2Sql when using DbLinq

Comment: @BlueRaja I tested and the solutions don't work

Comment: @Jader: DbLinq is not the same as Linq-to-SQL.  Linq-to-SQL refers to a specific Microsoft technology

Comment: @BlueRaja I know that. And I believe that it's impossible to use DbLinq without Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: @Jader Linq2Sql is not the same as DbLinq. The same way Linq2Sql is not the same as Linq2Entities, although both generate SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen it done like this:

```
 db.Table.Where(
            item => item.IsApproved.HasValue == isApproved.HasValue && 
            (!item.IsApproved.HasValue || item.IsApproved.Value==isApproved.Value ) 
 ).Count();
```

Comment: I added a similar answer that I am using. But yours works just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had this problem before, I remember that the problem is in converting the LINQ query to a SQL statement.

The second expression has an equal in SQL that:
    `Where IsAproved is null`

but the first expression does not because it is a comparision between a value in the database with a C# nullable variable.

To solve it, I would suggest to try:

```
db.Table.Where(item => isApproved != null ? item.IsApproved == isApproved.Value 
                                          : item.IsApproved == null).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework/2541042#2541042)

You should use

```
db.Table.Where(item => item.IsApproved.Equals(isApproved)).Count();
```

Then you should [contact](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015361-incorrect-handling-of-null-variables-in-where-cl?ref=title) [Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/607404/entity-framework-and-linq-to-sql-incorrectly-handling-nullable-variables) and let them know how terrible this behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the performance hit, but it works

```
bool? isApproved = null;
db.Table.Where(item => item.IsApproved == isApproved || 
                     !(item.IsApproved.HasValue || isApproved.HasValue))
    .Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

> db.Table.Where(item => item.IsApproved == isApproved.Value).Count();

Comment: This will crash, when isApprove is null