# Dynamic linq OrderBy() failing after adding HasValue in the expression

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, reflection, expression

I had followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265186/how-do-i-specify-the-linq-orderby-argument-dynamically) to create dynamic orderby clause in linq queries using Expression trees.

But later I came across a scenario where I had to sort the values of a column with keeping the null value in mind as my database column allows null
i.e. All the non-null values should be sorted ascending and then null values should be followed.

So I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461479/linq-order-by-null-column-where-order-is-ascending-and-nulls-should-be-last) to modify my dynamic LINQ code to handle the above scenario. i.e. I tried to add `HasValue` call in my `OrderBy()` call. But it started to fail with below error.

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

The argument that causes `Expression.Call()` to fail:

```
p.IsProcessStarted.HasValue
```

Below is the code that I am using:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(
     this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
   {
     string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
     var type = typeof(TEntity);
     var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
     var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
     bool isNullable = propertyType.IsGenericType
         && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);

     var parameter 
       = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
     MemberExpression propertyAccess
       = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
     MemberExpression hasValue 
       = Expression.Property(propertyAccess, "HasValue");            
     LambdaExpression orderByExpression
       = Expression.Lambda(hasValue, parameter);
     MethodCallExpression resultExpression
       = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, 
         new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression,
         Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));

     return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
   }
}
```

This is how I am calling the above extension method:

```
var res = myQuery.OrderBy("IsProcessStarted", true)
```

And the expression I want to build is `.OrderBy(p>=p.IsProcessStarted.HasValue)`

Comment: Please, show a sample of the lambda order-by expression that you're trying to implement with the expression tree. As it's written, it looks like the expression tree doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is what my call will look like.
var res = myQuery.OrderBy("IsProcessStarted", true)
And the expression I want to build is 
.OrderBy(p>=p.IsProcessStarted.HasValue)

Comment: Then my answer is correct. Make that change, and try it. However, take into account my note to check if is nullable or not to return a different expression in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to implement this `OrderBy`:

```
.OrderBy(p => p.HasValue)
```

This expression returns a `bool`. So, to make it work, you must specify the type correctly in the `Expression.Call` invocation, like this:

```
MethodCallExpression resultExpression
    = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command,
    new Type[] { type, typeof(bool) }, // Expression<Func<type, bool>>
    source.Expression,
    Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
```

*NOTE: I don't know if this is what you want, but the code compiles and runs correctly if you implement it like this. However, as I asked in the comment, you shoul show which lambda you want to implement. You should also modify your code to support the scenarios of nullable and not nullable properties. You are checking this, with `isNullable`, but you're not using it anywhere*

Comment: Thanks JotaBe, I am trying to write this in my expression OrderBy(p>=p.IsProcessStarted.HasValue). And the isNullable I will be using once I know how to prepare this query. I have edited my post to include what expression I am trying to build.