# c# linq order by null last

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of logs as a string. It is being output to me like this:

```
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7959: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Requested (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9019: DAIW - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9229: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219: DAIW - Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1229: c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647 - Client Successfully Retrieved Session",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1429: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - End Session Requested - Thread started"
```

This is in the wrong order.
It should be in this order:

```
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7959: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Requested (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9229: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",,
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1429: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - End Session Requested - Thread started"
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9019: DAIW - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219: DAIW - Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1229: c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647 - Client Successfully Retrieved Session"
```

It appears the old system is just ordering by date.
I have created a model and extracted the parts that I need.
The model looks like this:

```
public class TroposLog
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Now that gives me something to work with.
But I can't get it to be ordered in the way I wanted.
If I do this:

```
return troposLogs
           .OrderBy(m => m.UserName)
           .ThenBy(m => m.SessionId)
           .ThenBy(m => m.Created);
```

It returns this order:

```
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7959: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Requested (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9229: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1429: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - End Session Requested - Thread started",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1229: c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647 - Client Successfully Retrieved Session",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9019: DAIW - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219: DAIW - Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)"
```

I have also tried:

```
return troposLogs.OrderBy(m => m.UserName != null).ThenBy(m => m.UserName);
```

Which returns this order:

```
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:7959: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Requested (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9229: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1229: c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647 - Client Successfully Retrieved Session",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1429: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - End Session Requested - Thread started",
"2018.07.26 10:35:06:9019: DAIW - New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)",
"2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219: DAIW - Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)"
```

In this case, the date has taken over. But I need the session id to stay together.

Could someone help me with this?

This is an example of a tropos log (I have ignored data types, it is simply to show you how it ties to the string logs)

```
var logString = "2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Client successfully got the transaction result";
var log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = "2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889";
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Client successfully got the transaction result";
```

The log above, has no `UserName` or `ActionName`;

```
var logString = "2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219: DAIW - Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)";
var log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = "2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219";
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)";
log.UserName= "DAIW";
```

This one has no `ActionName`. And finally:

```
var logString = "2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169: 4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735 - Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success";
var log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = "2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169";
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success";
log.ActionName= "SOCS";
```

This one has no `UserName`.
I hope that helps to clarify

Comment: I can´t see how the log-messages are reflected in your data-structure. I see a date followed by some kind of identifier and then a message. But what´s with `ActionName`, `UserName` and `SessionID`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ order by null column where order is ascending and nulls should be last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461479/linq-order-by-null-column-where-order-is-ascending-and-nulls-should-be-last)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is to group the logs by SessionId and then order each group by date (I think) so you can try this:

```
        var troposLogs = new TroposLog[]
        {
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now, 
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735",
                ActionName = null,
                Message = "Client successfully got the transaction result"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735",
                ActionName = "SOCS",
                Message = "Run Transaction Requested (SOCS)... Success"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = "DAIW",
                SessionId = "c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647",
                ActionName = null,
                Message = "New Session Requested... Success (Start Session Thread Started)"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735",
                ActionName = "SOCS",
                Message = "Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735",
                ActionName = null,
                Message = "Client successfully got the transaction result"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = "DAIW",
                SessionId = "c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647",
                ActionName = null,
                Message = "Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647",
                ActionName = null,
                Message = "Client Successfully Retrieved Session"
            },
            new TroposLog
            {
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserName = null,
                SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735",
                ActionName = "",
                Message = "End Session Requested - Thread started"
            },
        };

        var orderedLogs = troposLogs.OrderBy(l => l.Created) // Just in case
                                    .GroupBy(l => l.SessionId)
                                    .OrderBy(g => g.FirstOrDefault().Created)
                                    .SelectMany(g => g)
                                    .ToList();
```

Note: To get this working, you need to assign the correct sessionIds to all log entries when you fill your model, e.g. all logs for 'DAIW' user should have sessionId 'c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647' which is the correct one according your input data (this should not be a big deal)

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
troposLogs.OrderBy(m => m.UserName == null).ThenBy(m => m.UserName)
```

So `UserName == null` is `true`, `UserName != null` is `false`, and the ordering of `bool` values is `false, true`.

Your error is that you are ordering first by `UserName` and then by `UserName` "is null"... But this second ordering is useless (because ordering by UserName has already ordered dividing `null` and `not null`). You must do the opposite (as I've done).

Test:

```
var troposLogs = new List<TroposLog>();

var log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = DateTime.ParseExact("2018.07.26 10:35:06:7889", @"yyyy\.MM\.dd HH\:mm\:ss\:ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Client successfully got the transaction result";
troposLogs.Add(log);

log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = DateTime.ParseExact("2018.07.26 10:35:07:1219", @"yyyy\.MM\.dd HH\:mm\:ss\:ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Start Session ThreadSuccess (c0c2311a-b509-4e6e-a236-80e2d86f2647)";
log.UserName = "DAIW";
troposLogs.Add(log);

log = new TroposLog();
log.Created = DateTime.ParseExact("2018.07.26 10:35:06:9169", @"yyyy\.MM\.dd HH\:mm\:ss\:ffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
log.SessionId = "4d50b064-d269-4256-a187-82a3f9402735";
log.Message = "Run Transaction Thread (SOCS)... Success";
log.ActionName = "SOCS";
troposLogs.Add(log);

var ordered = troposLogs.OrderBy(m => m.UserName == null)
            .ThenBy(m => m.UserName)
            .ThenBy(m => m.SessionId)
            .ThenBy(m => m.Created)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: I had tried that too, but it still didin't give the right order. I have updated my question above to show the result

Comment: @r3plica Updated answer