# Check object null inside orderby Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have one `list` with few records, `list` has another `object` inside it. Based on inner object I am using `OrderByDescending`. Inner object is `null` in few places so it is throwing `NullReferenceException`.

```
items.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement.CreatedDate).ToList()
```

When `Obj_Announcement` is `null` the query throws an exception.

Not duplicate: I have object inside `OrderByDescending` not single field.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ order by null column where order is ascending and nulls should be last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461479/linq-order-by-null-column-where-order-is-ascending-and-nulls-should-be-last)

Comment: To solve this you should at first decide wether how the `null` values should be sorted. Should they be lowest or highest?

Comment: @RenéVogt - I need latest records on top, this way I need.

Comment: The Net Library doesn't allow a null for a DateTime object.  Usually I use a new DateTime which sets default Date to 1/1/1.  Then I test for null by checking if the date is greater than 1/1/1.

Comment: You should order hasValue of inner object then order list by it's value: `items.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement.CreatedDate.HasValue).ThenByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement.CreatedDate.Value)`

Comment: You can also directly return the value to be used for sorting: p.OrderByDescending(q => property.GetValue(q) ?? 1) or even p.OrderBy(q => property.GetValue(q) ?? -1). So you can collect the null-values first, or last, how you need for your solution. I use this for my collections inside a generic function and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically got two options depending on the resulting set you're expecting.

1. Exclude the instances, which's `Obj_Announcement` - property is null. But imho that's not the scope of the question and would change the beavior of the program.
2. Explicitly decide on how to deal with nulls.

When looking at the documentation for `OrderByDescending` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending) one comes across the `keySelector` parameter. Since it's a `Func<TSource, TKey>` it should be able to deal edge cases a `TSource` instance could show - for example nulls on a child-object, in your case.
So imho the easiest solution on how to deal with that would be deciding whether you want to prepend or append the nulls to the list by

```
items.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement?.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToList()
```

or

```
items.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement?.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue).ToList()
```

But be aware, that `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` are only assumptions as default values. They do not reflect the actual state of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The neat method would be to separate your LINQ query from the way you define which item comes before another item. In other word: what is the sort order of Item X and Item Y

For this we need to create a class that implements `IComparer<Item>`

```
class Item
{
     public Announcement Announcement {get; set;} // your inner object, might be null
     ...
}

class Announcement
{
     public DateTime CreatedDate {get; set;}
     ...
}
```

Suppose you you have two `Items`, one of them has a null `Anouncement`.

```
Item item1 = new Item {Announcement = null};
Item item2 = new Item {Announcement = new AnnounceMent{CreatedDate=new DateTime(2000, 1, 1)}};
```

It's up to you to decide which comes first. Let's assume you want the null items at the end.

```
class ItemComparer : Comparer<Item>
{
     public static readonly ByCreatedDate = new ItemComparer();

     private static readonly IComparer<DateTime> dateComparer = Comparer<DateTime>.default;

     public override int CompareTo(Item x, Item y)
     {
         // TODO: decide what to do if x or y null: exception? comes first? comes last

         if (x.Announcement == null)
         {
             if (y.Announcement == null)
                 // x and y both have null announcement
                 return 0;
             else
                 // x.Announcement null, y.Announcement not null: x comes last:
                 return +1;
         }
         else
         {
             if (y.Announcement == null)
                 // x.Announcement not null and y.Announcement null; x comes first
                 return -1;
             else
                 // x.Announcement not null, y.Announcement not null: compare dates
                 return dateComparer.CompareTo(x.CreatedDate, y.CreateDate)
         }
    }
}
```

Usage:

(improved after comment by Peter Wurzinger)

```
var result = items.OrderByDescending(item => item, ItemComparer.ByCreatedDate);
```

Note: If you decide to change the sort order of your Items, all you have to do is change the ItemComparer class. All your LINQ statements that order your Items will then use the new sort order.

Comment: +1, this is great answer! But I think there is no overload for `OrderByDescending(IEnumerable<TSource>, IComparer<TSource>)` according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending. Imho the call should therefore look like `items.OrderByDescending(item => item, ItemComparer.ByCreatedDate);`
And it should be noted, that it is most likely not translatable when used with `IQueryable<TSource>` like OR-mapping, OData or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```
items.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Obj_Announcement?.CreatedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToList()
```

should work, as if the value is null, it will return `DateTime.MinValue` (meaning null values will be at the back), and otherwise, you will just retrieve the CreatedDate.

Please note that I am not in front of a pc right now though, so could not test.