# Linq order list with null reference inside

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

When I use EF Core linq query, and order the list by inner object's property. If the inner object is null, it will not throw exception.

- For example:

  ```
  var Posts = await context.Post
     .Where(p => p.BlogId == 1))
     .Include(p => p.Author)
     .OrdeyBy(p => p.Author.Name)
     .ToListAsync();
  ```

If one of `Author` in `Post` is `null`, the query still can be executed successfully.

But if I order a list, which is not query by EF Core. For example, I order an existing list `Posts`:

`Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Author.Name).ToList()`

It will throw a null reference exception. Like this metioned: [Check object null inside orderby Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744082/check-object-null-inside-orderby-linq)

What make their different? Why EF Core linq order is not impact by null reference?

Comment: The ToList() is causing the exception.  So remove the ToList().  Do it in two steps 1) var orderedResults = Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Author.Name); 2) If(orderedResults.Count() > 0) orderedResults = OrderResults.ToList();

Comment: you can try `Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Author?.Name).ToList()`

Comment: The difference is that in first example you load related data - Author, in second - you don't.

Comment: The first one is turned into a Sql Statement and executed on the database. The orderby expression never actually executes in your c# process, it is turned into a store sql expression and executes against your database as a query. The other example is executed in memory as code and runs in your c# process which would result in an NRE if the object instance was null.