# EF Core 3.0 conditional order by in LINQ when the condition is validated in DB

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

The following is a fairly simple example of the issue that I need to solve. I am using `EF Core 3.0` and with `LINQ`, I need to get all the guys from the database in a specific order. First I need all guys where it has a `Feature class` and the `Until` property is bigger than `DateTime.Now` ordered by the `At` property descending and then ordered by the `Id` property from the `Guy class` descending.

```
public class Guy
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Feature Feature {get;set;}
}
public class Feature
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime? At {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Until {get;set;}
}

_dbcontext.Guys.Add(new Guy{Id = 1, Feature = new Feature {At = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), Until = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)}})
_dbcontext.Guys.Add(new Guy{Id = 2, Feature = new Feature {At = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), Until = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)}})
_dbcontext.Guys.Add(new Guy{Id = 3})
_dbcontext.Guys.Add(new Guy{Id = 4})
```

Example `_dbcontext.Guys.Include(x => x.Feature).OrderByDescending(x => x.Feature.Until > DateTime.Now ? x.Feature.At : DateTime.Now).ThenByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();`
should return Guy with `Id 1` first as `Feature.At` property is greater than `DateTime.Now` and the rest should be sorted by the `Id` property descending. `Id 4`,
`Id 3` then `Id 1`.

Unfortunately, this example sort of works, but the issue is, first it will return the ones which has no `Feature class` (ordered descending by the `Id` property), then the ones which has a `Feature class` where the `At` is greater than `DateTime.Now`. Again these are ordered by the `Until` property correctly, but these should be on top.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: if the Until property is lesser than DateTime.Now, should it be part of the result set?

Comment: Yes, they all should be returned, but if the `Until` property lesser than `DateTime.Now`, it is be ordered by it's `Id`. 

Meaning first all guys that has an `Until` greater than `DateTime.Now` ordered by their `At` property descending, then the rest of the guys ordered by their `Id` descending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [LINQ order by null column where order is ascending and nulls should be last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461479/linq-order-by-null-column-where-order-is-ascending-and-nulls-should-be-last)

Add a condition in to filter by if the value is null or not. See the above post for example.

```
_dbcontext.Guys
.Include(x => x.Feature)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feature != null)
.ThenBy(x => x.Feature.Until > DateTime.Now ? x.Feature.At : DateTime.Now)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

Edit:

```
_dbcontext.Guys
.Include(x => x.Feature)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Feature!= null && x.Feature.Until > DateTime.Now ? x.Feature.At : DateTime.Now)
.ThenByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

I ran this in a console app and it came out 2,4,3,1

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but it is incorrect.If I run this, it will return 1,2,4,3, but `Id 1` should be ordered by it's `Id` property so the correct result would be 2,4,3,1. Also all ordering should be descending.

Comment: Ah i see the mistake. I have just replicated and tested and get 2,4,3,1. Answer is edited

Comment: Grant, I do not see any change in the answer yet:(

Comment: Refresh now, let me know if it helps

Comment: I do not understand why, but it works if you change the `OrderByDescending` to `OrderBy`. Otherwise I get completely wrong answer. Thanks Grant

Comment: Sorry, I have to take it back, because than the `At` ordering is incorrect. I will try it again to see if the problem is on my end, but if not, then it is still unsolved

Comment: hmmm.. curious. Sorry to waste your time. Good luck

Comment: Grant, I am sorry, you are right. Did a simple console app and it works there. There is another issue on my end which I need to find, but the `LINQ` query is correct! Thanks