# null in Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I em using Linq to EF and trying to get FirstOrDefault entitiy from ObjectSet.
The query looks like this :

```
        Notification not = new Notification();
        ........
        //not.SubTypeID = null;

        var elem = ent.Notifications.FirstOrDefault(p =>                     
                    p.ID == not.ID &&
                    p.SubTypeID == not.SubTypeID &&
                    p.Location == not.Location &&
                    p.TypeID == ns.TypeID
            );
```

Sometimes `SubTypeID` can be `null` and in this case nothing is returnced in `elem` althogh `p.SubTypeID` and `not.SubTypeID` are both `null`.

But the strange thing is that when I run this query :

```
        var elem = ent.Notifications.FirstOrDefault(p =>                     
                    p.ID == not.ID &&
                    p.SubTypeID == null &&
                    p.Location == not.Location &&
                    p.TypeID == ns.TypeID
            );
```

everything works as expected and I see data in `elem`.

So what I am doing wrong and what is the difference between these 2 queries when `not.SubTypeID` is `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i query for null values in entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the result of `null == null` is true.  But in SQL, which this expression tree is getting compiled into, the result of `NULL = NULL` is `NULL`.  Example on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL;
 ?column?
----------
(0 rows)
```

You might consider using an expression like:

```
p.SubTypeID == not.SubTypeID ||
(p.SubTypeID == null && not.SubTypeID == null)
```

This is kind of a hack, and there may be a better solution than this.  But the `NULL = NULL` test is likely the root of your problem.