# EF 4.1 / Linq-to-SQL: What is better: using Equals or ==?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

We're having a discussion about using `Equals` or `==` on an int comparison in a LINQ query. We're using EF4.1 Code First. What is better?

```
var query = context.Boodschappen
                   .Where(b => b.BoodschapID == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

or:

```
var query = context.Boodschappen
                   .Where(b => b.BoodschapID.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

And **why**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Linq To Sql, you want neither. Instead, use Object.Equals: `.Where(b => Object.Equals(b.BoodschapID, id)`

Why? Because of a Bug in the SQL Generator if id happens to be a nullable uniqueidentifier. If using b.BoodschapID.Equals(id) or b.BoodschapID == id and b.BoodschapID happens to be a nullable Guid, the generated SQL will not be `WHERE BoodschapID IS NULL` but rather `WHERE BoodschapID = @p0` which will not return any results.

I know for sure that EF used to have the same bug. No idea if it's solved yet. You can find more details [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/), just be aware that some of the answers generate horrendous SQL.

Apart from that, there is no difference between Equals and == in Linq To SQL that I'm aware of.

Comment: That bug only seems to be present in EF. I use Linq2SQL all the time like that with no issue.

Comment: @leppie I stumbled across it when I ran into exactly that problem with Linq To SQL on .net 4.0 :( See the linked question.

Comment: Interesting. Never had that problem. What side was the nullable?

Comment: BTW, no need to do `Object.Equals(...)`, `Equals(...)` works just as well.

Comment: I see now how that 'bug' can occur. Not that it would happen often, but I guess there are occasions :)

Comment: @leppie Both sides. Essentially: `public SomeObj Get(Guid? someId) { return (from row in db.GetTable<DbSomeObjs>() where row.SomeID == someId select row.AsBusiness()).FirstOrDefault(); }` would trigger it. `row.SomeID.Equals(id)` had the same issue. `where Equals(row.SomeID,someId)` fixed it without generating terrible SQL. The bug does not occur with `where row.SomeID == null`. Essentially the Expression Analyzer does not recognize that someID is NULL and treats it as a normal parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I 'prefer' the former. It works on nullable properties too.