# Linq to SQL .Equals returns true when comparing int to string --> Id.Equals("5") returns true

Tags: c#, linq

We have a new developer that is just now learning LinqToSql.  While going over his code, we noticed that he was using `.Equals` instead of `==` for a value comparison.  On top of that, he is comparing an `int` with a `string`.  What completely baffled us, was that it worked!

After doing some testing it appears to only work with LinqToSql.  Linq to objects returns `false` and just doing `int.Equals(“string”)` returns `false`.

Below is a simple test using two sql tables:

```
Customer
    Id(PK)(int)
    Name(varchar)
    CompanyId(FK)(int)


Company
    Id(PK)(int)
    Name(varchar)
```

```cs
Console.WriteLine("{0}.Equals(\"{1}\") returns {2}", 3, "3", 3.Equals("3"));
        using (WrDataClassesDataContext wrDataContext = new WrDataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var customers1 = from c in wrDataContext.Customers
                            where c.CompanyId.Equals("3")
                            select c;

            Console.WriteLine("int .Equals String Results: ");
            foreach (Customer customer in customers1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
            }

            var customers3 = from c in wrDataContext.Customers
                        where c.CompanyId == 3
                        select c;

            Console.WriteLine("int == int Results: ");
            foreach (Customer customer in customers3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);
            }
        }
```

**RESULTS:**

```cs
3.Equals("3") returns False
int .Equals String Results:
Mike
Joe
Candy
int == int Results:
Mike
Joe
Candy
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any explanation?

Comment: an important side note about the use of == versus .Equals() in LinqToSql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105732/ef-4-1-linq-to-sql-what-is-better-using-equals-or

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LINQ to SQL generates SQL code from your LINQ query. In SQL, a comparison of an `int` to a `string` is perfectly valid. What happens is that by using `.Equals`, you bypass the type checking the `==` operator does at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison is translated to SQL, and SQL behaves differently from C# and .NET Framework. It's similar to how `"a" == "A"` is false in C#, but may be true when it's part of a query.