# Linq With Multiple Where Conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 Drop Down Lists and a search button. The Drop downs provide the search criteria.
So, the values can be all, few or none of them.
The T-sql stored procedure would be foll. Is it possible to write a linq for the same.

```
Select customerId, productId, supplierId
From Orders
Where ( customerId = @customerId Or @customerId IS NULL )
  And ( productId = @productId Or @productId IS NULL )
  And ( supplierId= @supplierId Or @supplierId IS NULL )
```

I'm using .Net 4.0, Entity data model

Comment: Have you even tried? It is quite simple...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple WHERE clause in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679644/multiple-where-clause-in-linq)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742793/entity-framework-linq-is-null-is-not-null-issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very simple query, if you're not entirely sure how to do things in LINQ, check out the [LINQ 101 samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) by Microsoft. They offer an easy to glance at reference on the common tasks performed with LINQ.

Just shooting from the hip; assuming you have variables for `productId`, `customerId`, and `supplierId` the code below should work.

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var results = db.Orders.Where(o => 
            (customerId == null || o.CustomerId == customerId) 
            && (productId == null || o.ProductId == productId) 
            && (supplierId == null || o.SupplierId == supplierId))
        .Select(o => new { o.CustomerId, o.ProductId, o.SupplierId }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Note that the original SQL said `@customerId IS NULL`, not `customerId IS NULL`...

Comment: Thanks. Pretty late, didn't catch that.

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ, you have the possibility to only add a `Where` clause when it is actually needed:

```
var o = context.Orders;

if (userHasChosenACustomerId)
{
    o = o.Where(o => o.CustomerId == theChosenCustomerId);
}

if (userHasChosenAProductId)
{
    o = o.Where(o => o.ProductId == theChosenProductId);
}    ...

var result = o.ToList();
```

which might communicate your intent more clearly than the `OR`s. (Replace `userHasChosenACustomerId` and `theChosenCustomerId` by the appropriate methods of your drop down UI control.)