# Where Clause With Null Object Using Entity Framework v5.0RC

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

I was trying to do the following

```
    public IList<Category> GetMainCategories()
    {
         return _context.Category
                 .Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null)
                 .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                 .ToList();
    }
```

However, no matter what I try this returns no results even though I can see in the collection that ALL ParentCategory's are null? I have read EF has problems with nulls like this and have also tried

```
.Where(x => x.ParentCategory.Equals(null))
```

And

```
.Where(x => Equals(x.ParentCategory.Id, null))
.Where(x => Equals(x.ParentCategory, null))
```

But still same result? I'm lost? How the heck do I check if an object it null? When I inspect it in VS2010 is clearly states its null?

**Update**

I can get it working doing this, BUT its insanely inefficient!!! MUST be able to do this in the query or I'm rather shocked by EF! Any help greatly appreciated?

```
    public IList<Category> GetMainCategories()
    {
        var cats = _context.Category
                 .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                 .ToList()
                 .Where(cat => cat.ParentCategory == null)
                 .ToList();
        return cats;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the SQL generated by EF. And yes, EF's query capabilities lag behind LINQ to SQL, its predecessor, in a big way.

Comment: What does your model look like? The Category model?

Comment: When the query returns no result, I'm wondering in what "collection" you see that "ALL ParentCategory's are null".

Answer (score 0):

If the query ...

```
_context.Category
        .Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null)
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
        .ToList()
```

... returns an empty collection it means that all categories in the database have a `ParentCategory` or that the categories table is empty. That's all.

The fact that in the result collection of this query ...

```
_context.Category
        .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
        .ToList()
```

... every category has no `ParentCategory` doesn't prove that every category has no `ParentCategory` in the database.

Do you know the basics of loading or not-loading related entities with EF? I suggest to read this introduction for EF >= 4.1/`DbContext`: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: I am using v5.0RC with the dbContext and the .Include() method only wants to take a string? Doesn't accept a lambda? And I have no .Collection() method available?

Comment: @leen3o: You can try to add the namespace `using System.Data.Entity;` to your code file. If that doesn't help ask a separate question about this problem, I haven't used v5 yet. For EF 4.x at least the namespace would solve the problem.

Comment: fwiw, I discovered that resharper 7 (preview version, maybe #28?) intellisense was blocking the intellisense that allowed lambdas with include even when we had the using system.data.entity statement. JetBrains is aware of it and it might even be fixed by now. So if you do have System.Data.Entity but still are not getting the lambda intellisense support, that could be why.

Answer (score 0):

In your results it is not guaranteed that the references are actually `null` in the database even if you see `null` in your returned results.

Use this query to force EF to load the reference data:

```
public IList<Category> GetMainCategories()
{
     return _context.Category
             .Include(x => x.ParentCategory) // for the new EF versions
             .Include("ParentCategory")      // for older EF versions
             // .Where(x => x.ParentCategory == null)
             .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
             .ToList();
}
```

Note that the `Include()` method does not impact how the `Where` works, it just makes sure that when you view the `ParentCategory` property in debugger window (or access from code) you will have the data there.

Answer (score 0):

It might be outdated but I guess this is the answer you were looking for:

```
public abstract class YourContext : DbContext
{
  public YourContext()
  {
    (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = true;
  }
}
```

This should solve your problems as Entity Framerwork will use 'C# like' null comparison.