# Entity Framework select where null is using "FieldName = null" instead of "FieldName is null"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i query for null values in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework)

I'm using entity framework to as my DAL.
using the sql profiler i have intercepted the query to the database when i run the following line of code

```
 m_Context.DomainEntities.Where(e => e.EntityParentID == i_UnitID);
```

When `i_UnitID` equals `null`, the query that its generates is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[EntityTypeID] AS [EntityTypeID], 
[Extent1].[EntityID] AS [EntityID], 
[Extent1].[EntityName] AS [EntityName], 
[Extent1].[EntityParentID] AS [EntityParentID], 
...
FROM [dbo].[DomainEntities] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[EntityTypeID] IN ( CAST( ''1'' AS int), CAST( ''2'' AS int), CAST( ''3'' AS int))) AND ([Extent1].[EntityParentID] = @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=NULL
```

Notice that it's using `[Extent1].[EntityParentID] = @p__linq__0` in the where clause.
that of course dosent work, i need it to generate the following

```
[Extent1].[EntityParentID] is NULL
```

is there a different method of using entity framework to achieve this ?

Comment: Is is returning the incorrect data?

Comment: Yes there are two records where the parent id equals null and if i change the where clause to `EntityParentID is null` then the query returns the correct data.

Comment: Where is the link to the duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write

```
m_Context.DomainEntities.Where(e => e.EntityParentID == Convert.ToInt32(i_UnitID));
```

and check the generated SQL query.