# Linq query translation to SQL messes up null parameter values

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Here's a simple LINQ query:

```
var objs = db.Objects.Where(o => o.Field1 == val);
```

This translates to SQL query:

```
select * from [Object] where Field1 = @p1
```

Trouble is, the value of `val` can also legitimately be null.  And SQL doesn't like comparing nulls; it insists on the syntax `... where Field1 is null`.

Is there any way of doing this neatly, short of using a `??` / `isnull` operation?

Comment: This is a known bug in EF. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2541042/60108)

Comment: @Eranga - thanks, that looks like it's worthy of an answer.  Syntax slightly neater than the other one currently appearing below.

Comment: According to the other thread, this issue should be fixed with the newest version of EF. What version are you using?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - EF 5.0.  I guess they didn't fix it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This, again, is an EF weakness in LINQ support. Good old LINQ to SQL translated this properly depending on the runtime value of val.

I suggest you go with this:

```
var objs = db.Objects.Where(
   o => (o.Field1 == val) || (o.Field1 == null && val == null));
```

If EF translates this litterally, the SQL Server query optimizer will actually pick up this pattern and optimize it to an "equals-with-nulls" check. You can even seek indexes using this code pattern, it just works. In the query plans this shows up as `IS` in contrast to `EQ`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip.  I think `(val == null ? o.Field1 == null : o.Field1 == val)` will compile to neater SQL, won't it?

Comment: @Shaul I think that would compile to a `CASE` which I do not trust the optimizer with. One can check the plan, but I came to standardize on the pattern that I posted. In T-SQL at least it is the best one can get.

Comment: Yeah, this is a really nasty deficiency in EF.  IIRC there are a few more such nasty bits, such as that the sum of an empty sequence is null, rather than 0.  While the queries look like C# due to linq, you unfortunately cannot assume the semantics are.

Comment: @ShaulBehr - In my case it translates into:

'WHERE (([t0].[Field1] = @p1) OR ([t0].[Field1] IS NULL))''

Comment: @NicVerAZ what EF version is this? They added optimizations in recent versions. I have no recent EF experience and this answer is 3.5 years old.

Comment: My version is a bit old, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

How about [**.HasValue**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx)?

```
var objs = db.Objects.Where(o => !o.Field1.HasValue && o.Field1 == val);
```

Comment: Check your answer, I think there must be a typo... `o.HasValue` could not possibly work.

Comment: OK, that will compile now, but it doesn't do what I want - if `val` is null and `o.Field1` is null, it should satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Shaul sorry for a long wait reply, i tested in `EF5` the `.Where(o => o.Field1 == null);` and everything is fine, what `EF` you are using?, by the way, i already modified my answer

Comment: @Shaul, and then i tested in EF4.0 everything is fine again and i have used the MS-SQL2012 Express. – spajce

Comment: Don't worry about it, the question is already answered.  Thanks anyway for the effort.