# Entity Framework Linq equals value or is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, null

I am trying with linq to get a list of items from a view where the field LocationId is either a value or is null. The field LocationId is int?.

The code which i am trying is something like this:

```
var items = _context.Items.Where(
    d => d.LocationId == null || d.LocationId == query.Location).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, as seen with SqlProfiler the generated sql does not include d.LocationId == null.

What is different from the possible duplicate question is that there where only checking for a value is null. What i want is somewhere in the line of SELECT * FROM Items WHERE LocationId = @some_param OR LocationId IS NULL.

Edit: After the comments with the mapping not being right I have found the issue. 
The mapping was something like

```
HasKey(x => new { x.EquipmentId, x.LocationId});
```

Because it all comes from a view.
Seems like if LINQ sees a property as part of a key it will assume it is non-nullable, does not matter if the property is nullable (int?)

Comment: What SQL do you see generated?

Comment: What is `query.Location`, also a `Nullable<int>` or an `int`?

Comment: is `LocationId` nullable? i.e. is it int?

Comment: The generated sql only includes the  Where LocationId = @p0. Nothing about is null.

Comment: Also query.Location is int , not nullable

Comment: Why do you care about the generated query? Does the code work? Maybe the code is passing `NULL` for `p0`.

Comment: @Ndy, In case `LocationId` is an `int`. The expression `d.LocationId == null` would not compile.

Comment: it will compile, because it is `int?`

Comment: @haim770 The db field is int?, the query.Location is int, it compiles

Comment: @Ndy, Show your `Item` class definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i query for null values in entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Again - does the code work? If it does, why do you care about the generated SQL??

Comment: @haim770 public class Item{ public int? LocationId{get;set;} public string Name{get;set;} }

Comment: @HristoYankov the code does not work , it does not bring back the values that i want

Comment: @Ndy are you sure you DO have a record which has `NULL` for its LocationId column?

Comment: @HristoYankov yes , very sure . In sql i run something like Select * from Items Where LocationId = 4 OR LocationId IS NULL

Comment: As Abdullah suggested, maybe you have discrepancy between the database and the model. Regenerate.

Comment: @HristoYankov I am using CodeFirst with mappings. The model is generated ok.It is in use. If i query only for one or other, it works. What i want to do is to combine them.

Comment: @Ndy Apparently something is wrong with your entity model / mappings which is causing EF to assume your `LocationId` column is non nullable , hence removing that condition when generating the SQL query. Update the question with your entity class and configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping was wrong. Removed LocationId from the HasKey mapping.

Seems like if LINQ sees a property as part of a key it will assume it is non-nullable, does not matter if the property is nullable (int?)