# Linq Entity Framework Ignoring IS NOT NULL

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a table with a nullable column when I execute code as follows ...

```
IList<IChecklistQuestionEntity> questions = repository.Where(q => q.OriginalQuestionID.HasValue);
IList<IChecklistQuestionEntity> originalQuestions = repository.Where(q => !q.OriginalQuestionID.HasValue);
```

...what I see in profiler is ...

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[OriginalQuestionID] AS [OriginalQuestionID], 
    [Extent1].[Question] AS [Question], 
    FROM [dbo].[cklChecklistQuestion] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Question] ASC
```

and

```
SELECT 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C1], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    WHERE 1 = 0
```

The EF class is implemented as follows...

```
[Table("cklChecklistQuestion")]
public class ChecklistQuestionEntity 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the ID
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID 
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the OriginalQuestionID
    /// </summary>
    public int? OriginalQuestionID 
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }       

    [Required]
    public string Question 
    { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ICollection<ChecklistQuestionEntity> Revisions { get; set; }
}
```

Naturally I was hoping to see a Where IS NOT NULL clause on the first query and the 2nd a select on the table with where IS NULL.

I'm using EF 6.1.3 from my searches it appears this issue has been around but should be fixed.  Would EF 6.2 give me more joy on this issue?

EDIT: I've tried with and without the virtual key word on the OriginalQuestionID property

EDIT2: I've also tried without repositories and just the EF context

```
IList<ChecklistQuestionEntity> questions = context.Set<ChecklistQuestionEntity>().Where(q => q.OriginalQuestionID.HasValue).ToList();
IList<ChecklistQuestionEntity> originalQuestions = context.Set<ChecklistQuestionEntity>().Where(q => !q.OriginalQuestionID.HasValue).ToList();
```

And received the same result.

The create for the table looks like...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cklChecklistQuestion](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OriginalQuestionID] [int] NULL,
    [Question] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cklChecklistQuestion] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cklChecklistQuestion]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_cklChecklistQuestion_cklChecklistQuestion] FOREIGN KEY([OriginalQuestionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[cklChecklistQuestion] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[cklChecklistQuestion] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_cklChecklistQuestion_cklChecklistQuestion]
GO
```

EDIT3: I think this post suggests it should be fixed

[How can i query for null values in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework)

EDIT4: Perhaps it relates to this issue...
[Entity Framework Linq equals value or is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762604/entity-framework-linq-equals-value-or-is-null)

Although it is different as whilst OriginalQuestionID is not part of a primary key it is a foreign key relationship to the primary key on the same table

EDIT5: Apologies all... When I attempted to replicate this issue in a smaller application I found I had left out a crucial part.  I've amended the code above to include a Revisions property.  Plus you need the following Context.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected MyContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Commenting out the following resolves the issue
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistQuestionEntity>()
            .HasRequired(cq => cq.OriginalQuestion)
            .WithMany(cq => cq.Revisions)
            .HasForeignKey(cq => cq.OriginalQuestionID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those queries relate to those EF LINQ statements?

Comment: Please show us the CREATE TABLE statement for `cklChecklistQuestion`.

Comment: @mjwills there are lots of similar questions. Here's the one which made me think this shouldn't be an issue in 6.13.. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682429/how-can-i-query-for-null-values-in-entity-framework

Comment: Please update your post with that information.

Comment: @Mick I believe that linked question is related to using null values in variables, which results in EF using non-ANSI equals-operator when comparing nulls. Your issue seems to be quite different.

Comment: it might relate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762604/entity-framework-linq-equals-value-or-is-null

Comment: It should work fine, I do this type of queries all the time with EF 6.1.3. First two queries from profiler seems to be unrelated to your code at all. First does `ORDER BY` which is not shown in EF query, second is just completely unrelated.

Comment: The repository where method adds the order by.

Comment: @Evk you were partially correct I had left out code required to replicate the issue.  The code I had posted did not replicate the issue.  I've edited the question to include all the code required to replicate the issue

Answer (score 1):

OK it's not really a solution but the issue is caused by addition of a Revisions navigation property. Removing this statement resolves the issue.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChecklistQuestionEntity>()
        .HasRequired(cq => cq.OriginalQuestion)
        .WithMany(cq => cq.Revisions)
        .HasForeignKey(cq => cq.OriginalQuestionID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I believe this is a bug and it's related to the issue discussed here...

[Entity Framework Linq equals value or is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762604/entity-framework-linq-equals-value-or-is-null)

Whilst OriginalQuestionID is not part of a key on the table relating it to the primary key of the table seems to cause EF to stop believing it can be null.

I tried upgrading to EF 6.2, the issue remained.

The only work around I have is to remove the Revisions navigation property.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug to the EF github project here...

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/496