# Troubleshooting LINQ Query Performance in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm having trouble with a LINQ query after joining a new table to it. Actually, it returns the data I'm expecting and it runs fast in testing. However, it seems that, as more users connect to the database, the query begins to timeout. For example, everything was working fine for the first 30 or 45 minutes in Production, but then at about 8:20 AM, it started to timeout. Again, I assume this is due to increased usage of the database on the whole.

Here is a little background on the ASP.NET MVC (5) application, in case that helps.

- A user submits a referral to our clinic
- The referral contains one or more orders
- If the person information supplied does not match an existing person, I do several things, including inserting records in an "orders" table (one record for each order selected on the referral).
- If the person information supplied does match an existing person in our system, then I "hold" the referral in a queue until it is manually resolved by either matching it to an existing person or by overriding it and creating a new person in the system. At this time, any orders selected in the referral are created in the table.

So, the two main tables to think about in this scenario are the "referral" (named "Referrals" in my code) and "order" (named "ReferralPPAs" in my code) tables. Until now, I have not needed to link the query in question from the Referrals table to the ReferralPPAs table (linking the query to the ReferralPPAs table seems to be what is slowing the query down once database/application usage increases).

Also, in case this helps, the referrals are entered by external users, while the orders I created from the referral are worked in a separate application with internal staff as the users, though it's all in the same database. The ReferralPPAs table is probably being used pretty heavily most of the day.

The query looks like this:

```
            IQueryable<ReferralListViewModel> referrals = (from r in _context.Referrals
                                                           join cu in _context.ClinicUsers on r.ClinicId equals cu.ClinicId
                                                           /* Here is the seemingly problematic join */ 
                                                           from ppa in _context.ReferralPPAs
                                                                        .Where(p => p.ref_id == r.seq_no.ToString())
                                                                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                           /* End of seemingly problematic join */
                                                           join ec in _context.EnrolledClinics on r.ClinicId equals ec.ClinicId
                                                           join pm in _context.ProviderMasters on ec.ClinicId equals pm.ClinicId
                                                           join ml in _context.MasterLists on pm.HealthSystemGuid equals ml.Id
                                                           join au in _context.Users on r.ApplicationUserId equals au.Id
                                                           where cu.UserId == userId
                                                           select new ReferralListViewModel()
                                                              {
                                                                  ClinicName = pm.Description,
                                                                  ClinicId = r.ClinicId,
                                                                  ReferralId = r.seq_no,
                                                                  EnteredBy = (au.FirstName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (au.LastName ?? string.Empty),
                                                                  PatientName = (r.LastName ?? string.Empty) + ", " + (r.FirstName ?? string.Empty),
                                                                  DateEntered = r.create_timestamp,
                                                                  Status = ppa != null ? ppa.Status : string.Empty
                                                              });
```

So, without the join I make reference to above, I experience no problems and  it runs quite fast. Adding the join also appears to be fast, again, until a certain number of users are on the system (at least that's my assumption).

A couple of other things I've tried to help improve performance and prevent the problem. I set the UseDatabaseNullSemantics to True, which seems to make a big difference in the overall performace.

```
_context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

I also wondered if the problem was an issue of locking on the table in question, so I tried wrapping the query in a transaction to do a ReadUncommitted.

```
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
              //query
            }
```

Again, while this improves the overall performance a little bit, it didn't seem to ultimately resolve the problem.

If anyone has any thoughts, ideas, or suggestions on how to tackle this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with LINQ in this form, but why are you doing a `.Where` instead of another join? Does it not have left joins? Other thought would be that you appear to be changing data types by calling `.ToString` which gets real expensive real quick

Comment: dont be afraid to put some of these complex sql queries into the database as procs.  they can be pre-compiled and run a lot faster since the execution plan is already built.  Just because you can build a complex query with Linq doesnt mean is the best approach.

Comment: In order to get a LEFT OUTER JOIN (which is what I need here), you need to call DefaultIfEmpty() on the join. This is one example of the syntax that seemed to work. Regarding the .ToString(), I know that is expensive, but that is being done all over our system and believe it or not, it has not been a problem. I'm even doing it in another query that gets called on the same page load and it works quickly. Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: @Kevbo - I could do that if I wasn't doing searching, sorting, and paging in the controller this query lives inside. This is just the core query, but gets modified if any of those features are used.

Comment: I am using Stacify's Prefix tool and could give you a breakdown of how long the query is actually taking (about 600 to 800 milliseconds), so it seems that the query is fast enough. I can also run the T-SQL generated by Entity Framework and it seems to be equally fast in SSMS. I've looked at execution plans and added a couple of recommended indexes. Again, that helped, but I'm not sure what's happening as more users get on the system.

Comment: Are you storing the results in a session variable?  You may be running into locking issues if people are updating tables as you read from them.  You can use SQL Server to monitor the queries as then come in and see the status of them.  Keep an eye out for those that may be locked

Comment: @Kevbo - No, I am not using any session variables. I did try to address locking by wrapping the query in _context.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted). I mentioned this in the post and it does seem to make it marginally faster. I was hoping that was going to be the magic trick. I definitely think there could be something with locking, but I don't know why it still happened after wrapping the query in that transaction.

Comment: I would use the activity monitor and see if any of the queries are taking a long time and work from there.  You might find that there is a query that is holding up everything.  Thats where i would start looking.  There might be a dead lock happening.

Comment: @Kevbo - Agreed. There may be something else entirely that is locking the target table and therefore slowing mine down. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: From what I see, the problematic join seems to be the only one multiplying the result set (due to one-to-many) and also is the only one that cannot use index due to string conversion. I would try creating a persisted computed column and index on it, in order to try forcing index scan. Because if for some reason at some point SqlServer decides to use full table scan on ReferralPPAs and it contains a lot of data, that might cause the huge performance hit. Too bad that the critical column is not Guid type and not indexed (and constrained as FK).

Comment: If I take the EF-generated SQL and change this line LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[mngi_ppa_ext_] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[ref_id] = (LOWER( CAST( [Extent1].[seq_no] AS nvarchar(max)))) ...to... LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[mngi_ppa_ext_] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[ref_id] = [Extent1].[seq_no] ... then it runs super fast. The original SQL times out. Is there any way tell EF to output the code the second way?

Comment: It's like SQL server has no problem comparing a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER to a VARCHAR representation of it, but when you throw in the CAST part, it slows it way down. I understand that I am essentially telling it to do that in my LINQ query, though. Just thought I'd see if there is any chance of fixing that.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I am a little leery of adding a computed column to the ReferralPPAs table. It's a vendor table and I might be able to get away with it, but I don't have full control of it. Did you happen to have any thoughts about my previous two comments? I'm sorry to bother you, but do appreciate your advice.

Comment: No problem, that's why we are here :) Now, the problem is that there is no official way to remove the cast. I'm thinking of some hackery, will let you know when having something concrete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the additional information from the comments, looks like the `Guid` to `String` conversion in the join condition

```
p.ref_id == r.seq_no.ToString()
```

translated to

```
t1.ref_id = LOWER(CAST(t2.seq_no AS nvarchar(max))))
```

makes the query not sargable, while the implicit SqlServer conversion

```
t1.ref_id = t2.seq_no
```

works just fine.

So the question is how to remove that cast. There is no option for that and also query expression tree does not allow removing it. It would be nice if the SqlServer provider sql generator was doing that optimization, but it doesn't and there is no easy way to hook into it.

As a workaround I can offer the following solution. It uses a custom [`IDbCommandTreeInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.idbcommandtreeinterceptor(v=vs.113).aspx) and [`DbExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339110(v=vs.110).aspx) to modify the [`DbCommandTree`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.common.commandtrees.dbcommandtree(v=vs.113).aspx) of the query.

Here is the interception code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EFHacks
{
    public class MyDbCommandTreeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
    {
        public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
        {
            if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace) return;
            var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
            if (queryCommand != null)
            {
                var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new GuidToStringComparisonRewriter());
                if (newQuery != queryCommand.Query)
                {
                    interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                        queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                        queryCommand.DataSpace,
                        newQuery);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class GuidToStringComparisonRewriter : DefaultExpressionVisitor
    {
        public override DbExpression Visit(DbComparisonExpression expression)
        {
            if (IsString(expression.Left.ResultType) && IsString(expression.Right.ResultType))
            {
                var left = expression.Left;
                var right = expression.Right;
                if (RemoveCast(ref right) || RemoveCast(ref left))
                    return CreateComparison(expression.ExpressionKind, left, right);
            }
            return base.Visit(expression);
        }

        static bool IsGuid(TypeUsage type)
        {
            var pt = type.EdmType as PrimitiveType;
            return pt != null && pt.PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.Guid;
        }

        static bool IsString(TypeUsage type)
        {
            var pt = type.EdmType as PrimitiveType;
            return pt != null && pt.PrimitiveTypeKind == PrimitiveTypeKind.String;
        }

        static bool RemoveCast(ref DbExpression expr)
        {
            var funcExpr = expr as DbFunctionExpression;
            if (funcExpr != null &&
                funcExpr.Function.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EdmFunction &&
                funcExpr.Function.FullName == "Edm.ToLower" &&
                funcExpr.Arguments.Count == 1)
            {
                var castExpr = funcExpr.Arguments[0] as DbCastExpression;
                if (castExpr != null && IsGuid(castExpr.Argument.ResultType))   
                {
                    expr = castExpr.Argument;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        static readonly Func<DbExpressionKind, DbExpression, DbExpression, DbComparisonExpression> CreateComparison = BuildCreateComparisonFunc();

        static Func<DbExpressionKind, DbExpression, DbExpression, DbComparisonExpression> BuildCreateComparisonFunc()
        {
            var kind = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbExpressionKind), "kind");
            var booleanResultType = Expression.Field(null, typeof(DbExpressionBuilder), "_booleanType");
            var left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbExpression), "left");
            var right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbExpression), "right");
            var result = Expression.New(
                typeof(DbComparisonExpression).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null,
                new[] { kind.Type, booleanResultType.Type, left.Type, right.Type }, null),
                kind, booleanResultType, left, right);
            var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<DbExpressionKind, DbExpression, DbExpression, DbComparisonExpression>>(
                result, kind, left, right);
            return expr.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

and `DbConfiguration` to install it:

```
class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new EFHacks.MyDbCommandTreeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Tested and working in EF6.1.3 and EF6.2 with SqlServer database.

But use it with care.

First, it works only for SqlServer.

Second, it's hackish because I had to use internal field and internal class constructor in order to skip the check for equal types of the comparison operation operands. So some future EF6 update might break it.

Comment: This looks promising, but the code is not compiling for me. I have to admit--this looks a little intimidating, so maybe I'm just being a little gun shy about it. Also, does it matter where I put the MyDbConfiguration class? I am using EF 6.1.3 with MVC 5, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Yes, it does. It should be in the same assembly as the db context. The code itself is no more than intelligent find and replace - find `ToLower(Cast(guidExpr, string))` and replace it with `guidExpr` :) What about compilation, the code is using C#7, but can easily be made to use old style constructs if you tell me what doesn't compile for you.

Comment: Ah, that must be it. Inside TreeCreated, queryCommand is underlined (first saying that it's expecting a closing parenthesis and all other instances state that it is not recognized in this context). None of the static bools below the Visit method compile, either. It must just be a C# 7 thing because every line is underlined. Would it be helpful to have screen shots? Let me know how I can give you better information about it.

Comment: Once you start using these new little language sugars, it's hard to go back :) Anyway, now it should compile fine in older C#.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to go back and rewrite it, but I really appreciate it (and all of your help). It compiles now and it is outputting the SQL just as I expected. However, per your original suggestion of adding a computed persisted column, I did add one to the table. It seems that now the implicit compare between a VARCHAR and a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER does *not* work on this particular column (it works on other columns in other tables, so it seems the computed column caused this). So, I dropped the computed column, but the issue persists. I've searched for an answer, but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: So, when I try this, it outputs the correct SQL, but the server complains with, 'Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.' Again, I can run this query: `select * from mngi_referral_ r
inner join mngi_ppa_ext_ ppa on r.seq_no = ppa.ref_id
where r.entered_by = 'f662fd05-a0f9-4102-a5b4-54a3ba1a3e65'` in my dev database and it returns the error, but if I run a similar query in the same database it works just fine. Weird. I need to figure out if there is some weird artifact of the computed column hanging around. Checked indexes, etc., and nothing so far.

Comment: I was able to resolve that issue and now I am off and running with this solution that you provided. I hate to use the word amazing, but the impact of this "hack" is actually amazing. Because we have this issue with UNIQUEIDENTIFIERs stored as GUIDs all over the system, this seems to *vastly* improve the overall performance of the application. Honestly, performance was pretty good before (other than this new issue), but now page loads are happening in milliseconds. I'd love to know a little bit more about how it works if you're interested in walking through the code. This is fantastic.

Comment: Sorry, that should have read, "...UNIQUEIDENTIFIERs stored as VARCHARs all over the system..."

Comment: Glad it's useful for you :) The code is nothing special. The interceptor is called several times during the EF command building pipeline. We are interested only in query command (there are also insert, update and delete commands) and only before it is sent to the sql generator (`SSpace` stands for *storage* space). The visitor handles only expressions of type `expr1 compare_op expr2` with `expr1` and `expr2` being `string` type. Then we check if any of them is expression of type `ToLower(Cast(arg, string))` with `Guid` type `arg`, and if yes, the expression is replaced with `arg`. That's it.

Comment: That’s very helpful and just the kind of information I was hoping for. Much appreciated. Thank you once again for all of your help with this!